# How to make gnome always run a script, not ask if it should be displayed?

Tags: bash, scripts

I have written a script:

```
for FILE in *.svg
 do
  inkscape --file=$FILE --export-area-page --without-gui --export-pdf=${FILE%.*}.pdf
 done
```

which converts all SVG files in a directory to PDF. Whenever I run it from Nautilus (after making it executable), the latter asks me if I want the script to be run or displayed. I always want it run, not displayed. Can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Launch `nautilus` and go to *Preferences*->*Behavior*, you will find your choices.

Equivalentely, launch `gconf-editor` and set the value of the key

> `/apps/nautilus/preferences/executable_text_activation`

to `launch`.

Alternatively, create a launcher pointing to your script, and make it executable. This option is better, because involve the single script and not all executable text files.